# Fill in values based on signals in columns

Tags: r

In the data below I want to increment the cell values after each 1, but reset it to zero on the next cell if Z.out = 1. Here is an example.

Starting Data:

```
Z   B_1 C_1 D_1 E_1 F_1
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Desired Output:

```
Z   B_1 C_1 D_1 E_1 F_1
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   1   0
1   1   1   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   1
0   1   1   2   0   1
0   2   1   3   0   1
0   2   1   3   0   1
0   2   1   3   0   1
0   2   1   3   0   1
1   2   1   3   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I think I can use df <- df %>% transmute_at(vars(contains("_1")),) to target the right columns and replace them with the desired output, but I have not found the proper syntax for the functions part of transmute. I am trying to use cumsum() to carry the values through each column, but when I try to flip in back based on z.out I just wind up with errors.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(Z == 0 & lag(Z, default = first(Z)) == 1)) %>%
 mutate(across(-Z, cumsum))

      Z   B_1   C_1   D_1   E_1   F_1   grp
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 3     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 4     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 5     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 6     0     1     1     0     1     0     0
 7     0     1     1     0     1     0     0
 8     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
10     0     1     0     0     0     1     1
11     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
12     0     1     1     2     0     1     1
13     0     2     1     3     0     1     1
14     0     2     1     3     0     1     1
15     0     2     1     3     0     1     1
16     0     2     1     3     0     1     1
17     1     2     1     3     0     1     1
18     0     0     0     0     1     0     2
19     0     0     0     0     1     0     2
```

Comment: So this does work for the example given, but when you `mutate(across(-Z, cumsum)` you only exclude Z by name. What if I wanted to exclude any number of other columns? or would I just include the targeted columns A_1 - F1 somehow?

Comment: I don't know you real dataset, but you can include/exclude variables using the select helpers, such as `starts_with()` or `ends_with()`.

Comment: Thanks, I just played with it a bit and user `contains("_1")` to do it and it looks like it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Comparable to the approach of tmfmnk, the following also works:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = c(0, lag(cumsum(diff(Z) == 1), 1, 0))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-Z, cumsum)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```